# find fields with average greater than x and group by other field mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I have a query which find the goals average of football teams, group by teams.

```
db.matchs.aggregate([{$group: {_id:"$equipes_domicile", pop: {$avg:"$score_equipe_domicile"} } }])
```

but i want only select them with an average greater than 4.

Comment: Add a `$match` step to your aggregation

Comment: This an aggregation pipeline, an array of steps. Add another step to this array

Comment: thanks but how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
db.matchs.aggregate([
     {$group: {_id:"$equipes_domicile", pop: {$avg:"$score_equipe_domicile"} } },
     {$match: {pop: {$gt: 4}}}
])
```

The `$match` will choose only documents with `pop` greater than 4.

Comment: there is an extra } line 4 but thanks it works !

Comment: yes I had a limit time before be able to accept